# Any attempt to access uniform variables in shaders causes an access violation on Intel chips

Tags: c++, opengl-3

Here's a really strange question.

I have a very simple shader with a single uniform vec4, running in a program using GLEW and GLFW.  The program works perfectly fine on several machines with nVidia graphics cards that I've run the program on.

Problem is, when I switch over to my laptop with an Intel Graphics 3000 chip (which supports OpenGL 3.1, the version I'm targeting), ANY function call that attempts to set the value of a uniform variable (glProgramUniform4f, glProgramUniformMatrix4fv, anything else), the game crashes with an Access Violation.

Furthermore (and I know this isn't directly a problem, but I think it may have something to do with the solution), calls to glGetUniformLocation on the nVidia machines return small values, while the same calls on the Intel machine return large ( > 6 digit) values.

I would post code, but I'm not quite sure exactly what would be helpful.  If a solution doesn't jump out at you, but you have an idea of what sort of code I should post, let me know, and I'd be happy to oblige!

Thank you!

Comment: Tried gDEBugger?  Or this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591948/wierd-behavior-of-opengl-glgetuniformlocation

Comment: I'm not sure how the other answer helps.  I don't see a single reference to uniform variables there.  

I appreciate the reference to gDEBugger, and I'll give it a shot if I get a chance, but I'm not sure it would be helpful considering that I've gotten all the information I need previously from the VS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me!

glProgramUniform... methods are only available in OpenGL 4.x, not 3.1.

To get around this, I simply ensured that the program I wanted to change was bound, then used the corresponding glUniform... method instead.

Comment: if it's only supported on 4.1, why is it in the header???  i just got tripped up on this too...

Comment: hmm, maybe you are on OSX it seems to be included in gl3ext.h on OSX 10.8...  would be good to maybe explicitly not include that file so you don't accidentally use extension features